# Develop and Debug Atom Package

Tags: atom-editor

I have just began working on [Atom.io](https://atom.io/docs/) Package development, and based on [this tutorial](https://atom.io/docs/v1.0.11/hacking-atom-package-word-count), have learnt from how to create package development skelton file to how to publish your package.

However, I do not know how to check/debug/develop your package. I know I can use Jasmine via `alt-cmd-I` or Developer Console (for Atom is based on Chromium), still if you want to check the behavior of your package, do I have to re-publish or install your package manually every time?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When working on packages locally, here's the recommended workflow:

- Clone your package from GitHub using `apm develop <package-name>`. This will clone the package's repo to your local `~/.atom/dev/packages/<package-name>`
- `cd` into this directory
- Start Atom in this directory using `atom -d .`

Now you can work on the package, make changes, etc. Once you're ready to reload, you can use `View > Developer > Reload Window` to restart Atom with the changed package.

If you have your package sources locally on your machine, you can skip the first step (`apm develop`) and simply create a symbolic link from your sources to `~/.atom/dev/packages/<package-name`.

Comment: For me (Atom 1.9.9 on Mac) the reload menu item is found in `View > Developer > Reload Window`.

Answer (score 25):

## Already have a local repo of the package?

To add to nwinkler's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435735/1218980), if you already have a repo of the package locally, you can use

```
apm link --dev
```

to automatically create a symbolic link to the `~/.atom/dev/packages/` directory.

Make sure to completely restart atom in developer mode with

```
atom -d
```

or in ***View** > **Developer** > **Open In Dev Mode...***

If you just want to use a local package (not in dev mode), you can use `apm link` directly. And `apm unlink` to remove the symbolic link to `~/.atom/packages`.